# BASH filepath and file commands

Tags: bash, directory, filepath

I am trying to recreate the folder structure from a source in a target location and perform a command on each file found in the process using BASH.Based on some feedback and some searches I am trying to get this solution to work properly.  Right now it is breaking because the windows folders have directories with spaces that it refuses to find.

I was able to get this to work after installing some additional features for my cygwin.

```
source='/cygdrive/z/austin1/QA/Platform QA/8.0.0/Test Cases'
target='/cygdrive/c/FullBashScripts'
# let ** be recursive
shopt -s globstar
for file in "$source"/**/*.restomatic; do
    cd "${file%/test.restomatic}"
    locationNew="$target${file#$source}"
    mkdir -p "$(dirname "$target${file#$source}")"
sed -e 's/\\/\//g' test.restomatic | awk '{if ($1 ~ /^(LOAD|IMPORT)/) system("cat " $2); else print;}' | sed -e 's/\\/\//g' |awk '{if ($1 ~ /^(LOAD|IMPORT)/) system("cat " $2); else print;}' > $locationNew
done
```

Comment: I made a change to my answer that should take care of spaces in your file names; try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `bash` version is 4 or above, this should work:

```
source="testing/web testing/"
target="c:/convertedFiles/"
# let ** be recursive
shopt -s globstar
for file in "$source"/**/*.test; do
    newfile= "$target/${file#$source}"
    mkdir -p "$(dirname "$newfile")"
    conversion.command "$file" > "$newfile"
done
```

`${file#$source}` lops `$source` off the beginning of `$file`.

If you can guarantee that no files have newlines in their name, you can use `find` to get the names:

```
source="testing/web testing/"
target="c:/convertedFiles/"

find "$source" -name \*.test | while read file; do
    newfile= "$target/${file#$source}"
    mkdir -p "$(dirname "$newfile")"
    conversion.command "$file" > "$newfile"
done
```

Comment: not sure what this error is... invalid shell option namept: globstar

Comment: Hmm. I don't see `globstar` in the list of my shell options... also, will it recreate the path properly in the target directory or will each redirection attempt fail, saying the path does not exist?

Comment: @jheep It's a relatively new option (http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/globstar-new-bash-globbing-option). You may not have it on your system. I know I don't, so it's a bad idea to rely on this option if you expect compatibility across arbitrary systems.

Comment: I am using cygwin 1.7.11-1 i think? What would that line have done?

Comment: just researched that, would have been a great option if it worked on my build

Comment: @GeorgeSkoptsov Its a bash version 4 feature, and it doesn't sound like the goal here is a portable "use everywhere" script.

Comment: @George Looks like `globstar` was introduced in 4, I've added a notice to that effect.  And I forgot the `mkdir`, I've added that as well.

Comment: I installed some more features and was able to get the shopt line to work.  With a couple of tweaks I am now running the script, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to `find` to get the list of files:

You can do it as follows:

```
export IFS=`/bin/echo -ne "\n"`         # set field separator to new lines only
cd testing                              # change to the source directory
find . -type d > /tmp/test.dirs         # make a list of local directories
for i in `cat /tmp/test.dirs`; do       # for each directory
   mkdir -p "c:/convertedFiles/$i"      # create it in the new location
done
find . -iname *.test > /tmp/test.files  # record local file paths as needed
for i in `cat /tmp/test.files`; do      # for each test file
   process "$i" > "c:/convertedFiles/$i"    # process it and store in new dir
done
```

Note that this is not the most optimal way -- but the easiest to understand and follow. This should work with spaces in filenames. You may have to tweak it further to get it to work under windows.

Comment: cd "c:/TestingSource/"
find . -iname *.restomatic > /tmp/test.files
tar --files-from=/tmp/test.files -cvf /tmp/test.tar
cd "c:/TestingTarget/"
tar xvf /tmp/test.tar

didn't seem to work, am I missing something?  Also where would i perform a sed command on the files in this script?

Comment: @jheep Reload the page -- I've changed the answer because I misread your problem initially.

Comment: No reason for the temporary file, you'd do better to just use `for i in $(find -type d); do...`. Also, no spaces is not a very good assumption on a Windows machine.

Comment: @kevin Yes, I said that it's not optimal, but easiest to understand and follow. I made a change that should fix the whitespace assumption.

Answer (score -1):

I would look into a tool called sshfs, or Secure Shell File System.  It lets you mount a portion of a remote file system to somewhere local to you.

Once you have the remote fs mounted locally, you can run the follow shell script:

```
for f in *.*; 
do 
   echo "do something to $f file.."; 
done
```

EDIT: I initially did not realize that target was always local anyway.